# jenkins NON-GUI notification of core / plug-in vulnerabilities / warnings

Tags: email, security, jenkins, warnings, updates

Jenkins is great at telling me when there are updates available for Jenkins's core or when there are security vulnerabilities in plug-ins.  This it does with a "*nice-fat-red*" number of vulnerabilities on the top of the web page **when I am logged in**.  And when one clicks on that, you get a nice synopsis such as:

[image: Jenkins Published Warnings]
*(Yes, I've already updated my Jenkins instance to patch these issues, post screen-shot).*

However, I cannot find any system setting or plug-in which will notify me (presumably via email) when there is a core or plug-in update which is available to mitigate a vulnerability, or even when there are ANY updates to apply.

I have used the CLI (via SSH) to find a way to list the plug-ins with updates available, as in this very hackish approach which relies on the formatting of the `list-plugins` command:

```
$ ssh -l USER -p PORT JENKINS.domain list-plugins | egrep '\([0-9.]+\)'  | sort
ant                           Ant Plugin                       1.9 (1.10)
antisamy-markup-formatter     OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin    1.5 (1.6)
branch-api                    Branch API Plugin                2.5.3 (2.5.4)
...
```

But I have not found any way via the CLI to:

- distinguish between security updates and general/feature updates
- identify core updates

I've also looked at the jenkins log (/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.log on Ubuntu) to no avail.

**Specific question:** Is there a setting or plug-in (or even CLI method) which will provide the warnings / vulnerabilities without being forced to login to Jenkins' web interface and look manually?

**General question**: How should I go about ensuring that my Jenkins installation is *automatically kept* up-to-date, including all plug-ins?  Ideally this would be with respect to security vulnerabilities only, leaving feature updates aside.

Comment: You may want to subscribe to the [Security Advisories](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/jenkinsci-advisories) mailing list. There's long history on managing plugins and a [JSoC project](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/07/30/plugin-management-tool-phase2-updates/). There may even be some [documented issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org) on the gaps. No solutions.

Comment: Just to add, according to the Jenkins Security [Vulnerabilities in Plugins](https://jenkins.io/security/#vulnerabilities-in-plugins) page, it's only recently they started to, "Add metadata to the plugin site indicating vulnerable plugins to inform administrator who may already have the plugin installed. Displaying these warnings is supported from Jenkins 2.40 and LTS 2.32.2." You may wish to raise an issue (regular or security) to see this information be available by API or email notification.

Comment: Very useful comments - thanks @IanW